# Can two charges moving at same velocity in same direction accelerate each other in direction of their velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation

There are two positive charge $q_1$ and $q_2$ moving at same velocity $v$ in the  same direction as observed by an observer in S-frame. The distance between charge is $r$ in their inertial frame. Assume $v$ velocity is along +x direction parallel to x-axis. The observer is on x-axis too. Therefore, the distance between $q_1$ and $q_2$ observed by observer would be $r$ again.

[image]

[image]
Both charges are initially at points $p_1$ and $p_2$ as given in figure. The electric field released by $q_1$ at point $p_1$  reaches $q_2$ at point $p_4$ after $t$ time.

The angle between net electric field and velocity is $\theta$ or the angle between $P_1P_4$ and vector $v$.

The waves released from $q_1$ spreads in all direction and the electric field at any point on its wave's surface is perpendicular to the tangential surface drawn at that point. If we look at this image given below we will find that there is a component of electric field along the direction of the velocity of $q_2$.

The magnetic force is attractive and can be given by, $|F_3| = {q_1 q_2 v^2 sin\theta}/{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (ct)^2 c^2} =  {q_1 q_2}/{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2 \gamma^2 c^2} $

The electric force along direction $P_3P_4$, $|F_2| = {q_1 q_2 sin\theta}/{ 4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2\gamma^2}$

The net force along $P_3 P_4$, $|F|= F_2 - F_3 
= q_1q_2sin\theta (1 - {v^2/c^2})/{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2 \gamma^2 }$

Since $(1 -{v^2/c^2}) < 1$, $F$ will always be repulsive and therefore $q_1$ and $q_2$ will always move away with an acceleration as seen from S-frame.

There is also a force along the velocity of charges, $F_1$.

$|F_1| = q_1q_2cos\theta/4\pi\epsilon_0r^2\gamma^2$

All these resulted force show that the charges will accelerate in the direction of their velocity along +x direction. But these charges are at rest in the lab frame so they cannot accelerate in the direction of +x.

One frame says there would be no motion in +x direction while other says there would be some motion. I don't understand how this can happen. If there's is some force in one inertial frame then it cannot be zero in another any other inertial frame.

Comment: The acceleration of the charges will be in the direction of the forces on those charges.

Comment: The question is how can there be a net non-zero force in the direction of their velocities i.e, along x-axis. In lab frame the charges only move along y-axis not x-axis.

Comment: Based on your drawing, there can't be a force on the particles in the direction of their velocity.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question most easily and naturally we use the [covariant formulation of classical electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism) where (in natural units) the electromagnetic field tensor $$F^{\alpha \beta }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
 E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
 E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
 E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and the four-force $f_\alpha$ on a charge, $q$ is given by $$f_\alpha=\frac{d p_\alpha}{d\tau}=q F_{\alpha\beta}u^\beta$$ where $u^\beta$ is the four-velocity of the charge. Since we only care about the force on the charge we need only evaluate the field at the location of the charge. For concreteness let's focus on the force on charge $q_2$. So at that location in the rest frame of the charges we have $$ F^{\alpha \beta }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -\frac{q_1}{r^2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{q_1}{r^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and therefore the force is simply $$f_{\alpha }=q_2 F_{\alpha \beta } u^{\beta }=\left(0,0,-\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2},0\right)$$

Now, transforming to a (primed) frame moving at $v$ relative to the charge's rest frame we instead have $$F'^{\alpha \beta }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & -\frac{\gamma  q_1}{r^2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{v \gamma  q_1}{r^2} & 0 \\
 \frac{\gamma  q_1}{r^2} & \frac{v \gamma  q_1}{r^2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and $$ u'^{\beta }=(\gamma ,\gamma  v,0,0) $$ which gives $$f'_{\alpha }=q_2 F'_{\alpha \beta } u'^{\beta }=\left(0,0,-\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2},0\right)$$

Therefore, there is no component of the four-force in the $x$ direction in either frame. Furthermore, since the four-force is perpendicular to the $x$ axis, the magnitude of the $y$ component is the same in both frames. Note, this does not imply that the magnitude of the three-acceleration is the same in both frames as the relationship between the four-force and the three-acceleration is not straightforward.

I believe that where you got confused in your analysis was in applying the Coulomb-like law to moving charges. Instead, you should use the [Lienard Wiechert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) fields if you don’t want to use the covariant approach.

Comment: This derivation is incomplete.  $r^2$ has to be Lorentz transformed to $r'^2$.

Comment: In this case $r’=r$ so I didn’t bother

Comment: Why can't i use coulomb force for this calculation. Why is it wrong to do it? The force i calculated were  not complete but needed to be calculated by using time too. But what i wanted to point is that there is a force along velocity when i used coulombs law to derive it. You are using already developed methods to derive force but i was looking for derivation at the basic level.

Comment: @JamesWebb Coulomb’s law is only valid for electrostatics. It doesn’t apply for an electrodynamic scenario. So you can only use it in the rest frame, not in the frame where the charges are moving. In that frame you need the Lienard Wiechert fields. Btw, based on the questions you ask, you really should learn the covariant approach. It makes everything you are asking very easy. It is a one time investment in your time that will greatly aid your understanding

Answer (score 1):

This setup is equivalent to the Trouton-Noble experiment that demonstrated that any acceleration on either charge would be along the direction of the distance between the charges in any frame.  The acceleration is NOT in the direction of the forces you calculated.  The key equation is $\frac{d\bf p}{dt}= m\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{\bf v}
{\sqrt{1-{\bf v}^2}}\right]
= m[\gamma{\bf a}+\gamma^3{\bf v(v\cdot a)}]
=m\gamma^3[{\bf a}+{\bf v\times(v\times a)}]$.
Your calculation of the forces is also wrong. The electric and magnetic fields are given in most EM textbooks.  Your method would have to use the Lienard-Wiechert fields.